# Reference request-Natural equivalence detected pointwise for complete Segal spaces

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories

I am looking for a reference for the following elementary assertion on complete Segal spaces:

> Let $A$ be a bisimplicial set and let $W$ be a complete Segal space. A morphism of $W^A$ is an equivalence if and only if, for each $a\in A_{0,0}$, its image under the map $W^{A}\to W^{\{a\}}\cong W$ is an equivalence of $W$.

I know a proof (which is also valid for Segal spaces), but I suspect that the proof of such an elementary assertion must already be recorded elsewhere. Can anyone locate a reference? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion is stated and proved as Proposition 2.21 in [arxiv.2311.01101](https://arxiv.org/abs/2311.01101).